# ASP.NET Can't Load Assembly

Tags: asp.net, dll

My computer crashed and I'm now unable to start my previously working ASP.NET Web Application in Visual Studio 2008 -- getting the following error:

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = Adam-PC\Adam
LOG: DisplayName = log4net
 (Partial)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/Adam/Desktop/SV/sview/Src/StoredProcedureTest/SV.Common.Web/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\SV\sview\Src\StoredProcedureTest\SV.Common.Web\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\SV\sview\Src\StoredProcedureTest\SV.Common.Web\web.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Adam/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/b898aa04/e528dbc7/log4net.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Adam/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/b898aa04/e528dbc7/log4net/log4net.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Adam/Desktop/SV/sview/Src/StoredProcedureTest/SV.Common.Web/bin/log4net.DLL.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\SV\sview\Src\StoredProcedureTest\SV.Common.Web\web.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80070057). Probing terminated.

Stack Trace: 


[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'log4net' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))]

[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))]
   System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection) +0
   System.Reflection.Assembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection) +43
   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +127
   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +142
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +46

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +613
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +203
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +105
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +178
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler..ctor(VirtualPath configPath, Boolean supportLocalization, String outputAssemblyName) +54
   System.Web.Compilation.ApplicationBuildProvider.GetGlobalAsaxBuildResult(Boolean isPrecompiledApp) +232
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileGlobalAsax() +51
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +337

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException() +58
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +512
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters) +729

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +8921851
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +85
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) +259
```

Comment: Did you try adding the reference back in?

Comment: Yeah I tried that.  It was a temporary files cache problem.  See below.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The answer is I had to delete this folder's contents:

C:/Users/Adam/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/

Comment: @frabiacca I had this same issue immediately after a power failure, related to Kev's answer

Answer (score 19):

After a BSOD, I had same error code but with AutoMapper.dll in VS 2010 for a .Net 4.0 MVC 3 project.  The resolution for me was to delete the contents of:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\temp

(This is on Windows 7 x64)

It seems the error message 'Bind result: hr = 0x80070057. The parameter is incorrect.' can be caused when a temporary copy of a referenced DLL becomes corrupted by a system failure.  The resolution is to remove this temporary copy.  Then when you re-compile the compiler will re-copy the original DLL to the temporary folder.

Comment: Same deal except I had to delete contents of C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root

Comment: also you may need to check C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files  (Note the Framework64)

Comment: Mine was solved by deleting the contents of %LocalAppData%\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\  but +1 for providing a solid explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 7):

Full list of paths to check and delete:

```
%LocalAppData%\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\
%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\
%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\
%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\
%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\
```