# All DLLS in site fail to load, exception 0x80070057

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll

My C# web application stopped working for no apparent reason, while a similar application on the same server still works. Looking for ideas what could be going on and how to fix it.

Yesterday I launched a build of the site with some minor updates. The server apparently went down during the build, because for a few minutes TeamCity displayed a message indicating the connection had been lost. However, it recovered and resumed the build.

After the build, I was no longer able to load the site. The home page now seems to be the only page that can load, and it displays incorrectly because the scripts and stylesheets fail to load. If I check the browser’s error console I find reports of multiple server error 500’s, where the referenced css and script files are failing to load.

The server is IIS on Windows Server 2008.

If I go to the server and open the site there, the page gives me error messages saying, “Could not load file or assembly ‘Antlr3.Runtime.Debug’ or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG)).”

Initially it was reporting the same message for a different file, AntiXssLibrary. I removed that DLL from the project, and the site switched to complaining about antlr instead. It looks like the problem isn’t either DLL, but something else.

On my machine, a nearly identical copy of the same code works without problem. Another copy of the site on the same server, a slightly earlier version of our software, works just fine.

I deleted all of the temp files recommended for this error, redid the build, restarted the machine, and deleted the bin directory and repeated the build. I’m skeptical that uninstalling or reinstalling any versions of the .net framework would help, given that the other site works—any problem with the frameowkr ought to affect both of them.

I turned on assembly logging, which gave me lots of additional information that didn’t help at all.

Any suggestions what could be going on?

Edit: a link below suggests that the problem is corrupted temp DLLs, and that deleting and recompiling will replace them with good copies. That's plausible. But it seems like re-running the build ought to recompile if anything is going to.

Might there be some other way to force it to recompile / update the DLLs?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809149/asp-net-cant-load-assembly)?

Comment: Zespri, thanks for the suggestion. The recommendations on that page are to delete temp files in various locations, and I've deleted from all of them. It did have a bit of good back discussion, which was helpful.

Comment: Problem solved, I guess. I created a new web site, pointed to the same location and the same port as the old one. That resolved the problem and avoided the need to update any settings.

Comment: Refer this link will resolve your answer.
[exception 0x80070057](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37412239/net-core-is-not-running-in-windows-2008-server-r2)