# .NET Core is not running in Windows 2008 Server R2

Tags: .net, coreclr

I installed the [DotNetCore.1.0.0.RC2-SDK.Preview1-x64.exe](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows) in my Windows 2008 R2 x64 machine. When I try to run a `dotnet` command the following error occurs:

[image]

```
C:\Users\Administrator>dotnet --version
Failed to load the dll from [C:\Program Files\dotnet\hostfxr.dll], HRESULT: 0x80070057
```

I double-checked that my OS is x64 and I'm installing the x64 version of .NET Core. Also, my installation seems to be okay, the file `C:\Program Files\dotnet\hostfxr.dll` exists on my machine.

[Searching](https://www.google.es/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22c:%5Cprogram%20files%5Cdotnet%5Chostfxr.dll%22) on [Google](https://www.google.es/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=net%20core%20hostfxr.dll%200x80070057) doesn't help a lot about the error. Maybe am I missing some pre-requisites?

Comment: You are testing an alpha version of a beta release, pioneers have arrows in their back.  Maybe you ought to wait until they are done, maybe you ought to file the crappy error reporting as a bug, maybe you need to tell them a lot more about the OS configuration.  And maybe you can figure it out yourself with a debugger or Process Monitor, open source is heavily fix-it-yourself troubleshooting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please update your OS through Windows Update or try installing [KB2533623](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2533623) to workaround the issue you are having. Also, thank you for reporting this issue, we'll get the documentation updated to reflect this requirement.

In the future, you can report, discuss and track issues with .NET Core on GitHub:

*Tooling:*
https://github.com/dotnet/cli

*Framework Libraries:*
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx

*Runtime:*
https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr

**UPDATE**: Prerequisites Documentation

https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/Documentation/prereqs.md#windows-dependencies